# What is meaning of swastika (卐) symbol in hinduism

Tags: symbols

I see 卐 symbol in one or two Hollywood movie(s) but I know its a Hindu symbol.So I want to know what is meaning of swastika symbol. is it used in other religions also?

Comment: Asking about religon makes it off-topic, you should remove that line.

Comment: [What is the significance of the swastika?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/158/what-is-the-significance-of-the-swastika)