# Swastika in Scriptures

Tags: scripture, puranas, yajur-veda, swastika

Swastika is Auspicious symbol for Hindus. I have only heard about the significance of Swastika no solid proof from Shastras. Where is swastika mentioned in Yagna Rituals specifically Yajurveda if it is/was ever used in Yagnas. If it has some puranic importance where is it mentioned in puranas.

There is a saying that Swastika symbol is specifically used for worshiping Ganesha.

[Related](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/158/what-is-the-significance-of-the-swastika?s=1%7C1.3602)