# Is the mirrored image Swastika forbidden or inauspicious?

Tags: scripture, symbolism, symbols, resource, swastika

There is already a question about the [significance of the swastika](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/158/what-is-the-significance-of-the-swastika) and Pandya's answer describes it in detail, but one part of it says :

> Note: only right Swastika is almost used and reverse (left) Swastika is believed inauspicious sometimes.

I have also heard this too. Right swastika is this:

[image]

And this is the left swastika/mirrored image swastika:

[image]

Is there any indication in scripture itself that what we call the mirrored image swastika is inauspicious or forbidden?

Comment: As a sidenote, tilted Swastika is auspicious (the one on Nazi flag, but not black colored). See pic of [this Shiva Temple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQdck.jpg).

Comment: As per whom the left swastika is believed inauspicious? Any reference?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That is the point of question, I have heard that many time from people and looking for a sourced answer.

Comment: @AnkitSharma its wrong belief. All forms are auspicious. There are hindus who use reverse swastika also but less.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi That's why I asked the question in first place to know if there is any proof to say otherwise.

Comment: The swastika to the left has a different meaning than the one to the right, but its not inauspicious. I had a reference, but don't remember where. I'll try and find it.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I will wait for it :)

Comment: Cannot find the source from before. The right handed one is associated with Kala, Time, and is considered to bring prosperity and good fortune. The left handed one is opposite, and is associated with Kali and Tantra. If you consider Kali unlucky, then it is unlucky. But of you consider Kali your protectoress, then it is lucky.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Kali ma is our kuldevi so I can't consider it unholy ;)

Answer (score 3):

Any form of Swastika or its mirror image cannot be looked upon as inauspicious. This symbol is found in many of ancient civilizations in different forms.

In the Eastern religions like Buddhism which are close to Hinduism also it is used as a sign of auspiciousness.

In various civilizations across the world. Right, left, and tilted forms of swastika are used widely.

In Hinduism also there is no reference of any swastika being inauspicious.

Below are some of the ancient forms of swastika used in various places of the world. All of them are used as symbol of auspiciousness. Especially in Buddhism.

Even Indus Valley civilization also there is one ancient reverse swastika mark which suggests its association with Hinduism.

Though in the present day hinduism and Jainism the mirror image is rarely used.

Image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika).

- Indus Valley Swastika

[image: Indus Valley Swastika]

- Byzantine Swastika

[image: Byzantine Swastika]

- Japanese Swastika

[image: Japanese Swastika]

- Ethiopian Swastika

[image: Ethiopian Swastika]

- Sri Lanka Swastika

[image: Sri Lanka Swastika]

- Greek Swastika

[image: Greek Swastika]

Comment: I am not interested in answer from other religion's point of view but from Hinduisms only and based on some scripture ( Veda/Purana/Smiritis etc).

Comment: @AnkitSharma So you don't consider Indus valley as hindu? There are no such references in indian scriptures.

Comment: Calling Indus valley civilization religion  as Hinduism will be a another debate.

Comment: @AnkitSharma then what does "hindu" mean? It is well known fact that our civilization flourished on the banks of Indus/Sindhu.