# Is there any mention of Swastika in Vedic mathematics?

Tags: vedic-rituals, mathematics, swastika

[image][image] 
Is Swastika possibly a physics or mathematics symbol, like ohm or pi?

Comment: No why would it be?

Comment: Related [What is the significance of the swastika?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/158/5212). It is used in rituals. It is not considered as a mathematics symbol in rituals.